# Разместить элементы вертикально

Tags: html, css3

Привет.

У меня есть список `<ul>`, в нем находится много вложенных `<li>` с другими списками. В общем - карта сайта.

Мне надо в родительском списке разместить все `<li>` один под другим и чтобы они располагались по колонкам в зависимости от высоты родительского списка.

Как я могу это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть вы приложите небольшой пример с иллюстрацией, схемку там какую-нибудь, не очень понятен какой нужен результат.

Comment: Вот первое что попало в картинках: http://druweb.ru/assets/images/WP/HTMLSitemap.gif

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, взгляните на пример: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/mphk5vrs/
минимальные модификации списка и все выглядит как на вашем скрине.

```
.sitemap {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: square;
}
.sitemap ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне необходимо чтобы колонки распологались в ряд, если не хватает высоты. Все в одну колонку я и сам могу :)

Comment: Видите, у вас вопрос был очень расплывчатый. Чтобы создать колонки вы можете сделать так:
1. Использовать CSS Multicolumn
2. Разбивать на колонки на сервере
3. Использовать вот этот полифил например: https://github.com/hamsterbacke23/multicolumn-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Для получения колонок можно воспользоваться.. колонками о_О

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Выбирай желаемые свойства из `column-count`, `column-gap`, `column-width` и `columns` и используй. Ну и вообще все посмотри - может ещё что пригодится.

http://htmlbook.ru/css/columns

Comment: Спасибо за совет, воспользовался колонками - классная штука. Но оказалось что это всё должно работать и IE8+, а колонки поддерживаются только в IE10+. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @trauma, скрипты в руки. Я не могу придумать никаких стилей, подходящих для IE8.

Comment: Воспользовался jQuery Columnizer - крутая штука, спасибо за совет.